# can I use addEventListener in a for loop with img elements

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I understand that addEventListener isn't IE friendly, but I'm curious about this approach in general.

I'm trying to use an 'onload' addEventListener with imgs in a loop, other than my function not firing it looks like the event listener is only being added to the first element. The images paths are coming from some PHP and I'm trying to take the onload out of my HTML.

Originally I had it like this (excerpt of HTML from a PHP while):

```
<img 
onLoad="SLIDESHOW.crkarchProject.onImageLoad(<?php echo $rowSlideImage[1]; ?>)" 
id="<?php echo $rowSlideImage[1]; ?>" 
src="./slideshow_images/<?php echo $rowSlideImage[2]; ?>" 
alt="<?php echo $rowSlideImage[3]; ?>"/>
```

What I'd like to do is use addEventListener in my loop for each image. This is the code excerpt I'm working on now:

```
// get the images and how many
photos = slideshow.getElementsByTagName("img");
totalImageCount =  photos.length;
for (i = 0; i < totalImageCount; i += 1) {
    var elem = photos[i];
    elem.addEventListener('onload', doIt, false);
}

function doIt() {
    console.log("YO!");
}
```

Is my approach all wrong? Is that var elem a bad idea in the for loop? I've also tried:

```
// also tried this in the loop
photos[i].addEventListener('onload', doIt, false);
```

Should I just avoid addEventListener all together (b/c of the IE thing). I do see the doIt firing when I use elem.onload directly in the loop.

```
// this will fire the doIt!
elem.onload = doIt();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
 elem.addEventListener('load', doIt, false);
```

You got the event type wrong. Yours refers to `attachEvent`. For a full list of event types have a look at [here](http://help.dottoro.com/larrqqck.php).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that link!! I was for something like that on the MDN.

Comment: The link is actually listed on MDN ,-)

Comment: That Dottoro is nice with the Support and HTML reference for sure. Here's a lising I found on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use JQuery, it's compatible with almost all browsers, and very easy to write what you are trying to do:

```
$('img').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
  console.log("YO!");
});
```

However, your code seems to be right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only attaching one listener (which is the vast majority of cases), the simplest way is to just add it to the appropriate property:

```
var i = document.images.length;
while (i--) {
  document.images[i].onload = doIt;
}
```

which will work in every browser that supports scripting.

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes sense now and avoids the IE problem. I'm going to do that, thanks!